# "Can't resolve 'fs' in bindings" when importing redis?

Tags: node.js, webpack, redis, fs, node-redis

I'm trying to use the [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) module to look up a key value in a redis table. However, the very import itself (`import redis from 'redis'`) is throwing the following error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'fs' in '/home/ubuntu/proost/web/node_modules/bindings'
>
> > Build error occurred Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
> >         at build (/home/ubuntu/proost/web/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:6:847)
> >     error Command failed with exit code 1.

I tried reading up the module's documentation but couldn't find any reference to this issue. For what it's worth, my `next.config.js` file (a custom NextJS extension of Webpack) looks like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */

import path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin from 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin';
import withSass from '@zeit/next-sass';
import withCSS from '@zeit/next-css';
import withPurgeCss from 'next-purgecss';

// dotenv.config();
const { parsed: localEnv } = dotenv.config();

module.exports = withCSS(withSass(withPurgeCss({
  distDir: '.build',
  purgeCssPaths: [
    'pages/**/*',
    'components/**/*',
  ],
  webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      return config;
    }
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          BASE_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL),
          REDIS_HOST: JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIS_HOST),
          REDIS_PORT: JSON.stringify(process.env.REDIS_PORT),
        },
      }),
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv),
      new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1,
      }),
    );
    config.optimization.minimizer.push(
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
    );
    return config;
  },
})));
```

Any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're trying to build a JS bundle with Webpack which should be used in browser's JS. But you can't use that `redis` package for browser's JS, it's only to be run in Node.js.

Comment: But I'm calling this snippet on the server (`if(!process.browser)`. Is there any way to make Webpack ignore this error?